# Invalid license data, Reinstall is required when running an exe

Tags: windows, registry

I have written a utility to made some registry changes. I ran it on my development premises on various machines and it works absolutely fine but one of our machines is getting an error when I run that utility.

[Invalid license data, Reinstall is required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sv07M.png)

I am stuck here, What could be the problem?